# Namespace for declaring SHACL Shape

Tags: namespaces, rdf, shacl

I am trying to write a SHACL shape for RDF data graph validation. I am having a bit of confusion about which namespace is used for declaring the name of the shape. I saw the SHACL documentation. The following namespaces are declared in it.

```
rdf:    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
rdfs:   http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
sh: http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#
xsd:    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
ex: http://example.com/ns#
```

While writing the shape, they used 'ex' as the namespace for declaring the name of the shape as follows:

```
ex:PersonShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:Person ;    # Applies to all persons
    sh:property [                 # _:b1
        sh:path ex:ssn ;           # constrains the values of ex:ssn
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
        sh:datatype xsd:string ;
        sh:pattern "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$" ;
    ]
```

I am not sure how is it decided which namespace is to be used for declaring the name of the shape. Could anyone guide me on this please?

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: The namespace is not important. The shape should be identified using an URI well, because it needs to be identified in order to even refer to it during validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IS4 mentioned, the namespace isn't *super* important, but if you wanted to use your ontology's namespace - no one would complain. It's common to combine both ontology *and* shapes together in the same file, which is where this practice makes more sense.